# Double integral that seems to go over undefined region

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area

> Evaluate $\int_R {8\over7}x^2y^{−3}dydx$ where R = {$(x, y) : 1 ≤ x, y ≤ 2, x ≥ y$}.

I believe that the integral should be $$\int_1^{3}\int_0^{x}  {8\over7}x^2y^{−3}dydx $$

However when I put this into a calculator, it says "undefined", obviously because of putting $0$ into the $y^{-3}$ of the inner integral.  When I do it myself with limits it doesn't help as the inner integral becomes $ \infty $ (and the correct solution to the entire double integral is $.7619$)

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The notation $\int_{\lim 0}^x$ is meaningless. Presumably you mean $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0} \int_a^x$, but you can simply write $\int_0^x$.

Comment: Thank you, fixed that.

Comment: Does $1\le x,y\le2$ mean two separate inequalities, $1\le x$ and $y\le2$, or does it mean both $x,y$ are between $1$ and $2$?

Comment: I believe separate.

Comment: However, it seems that @mfl is taking it to mean both and is arriving at the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $1\le x,y \le 2$ and $y\le x$ the integral is

$$\int_1^{2}\int_1^x  {8\over7}x^2y^{−3}dydx.$$

> What am I getting wrong here?

Your limits of integration are wrong.

> $\int_1^{3}\int_0^{x}  {8\over7}x^2y^{−3}dydx$

You are assuming $0\le y\le x$ and $1\le x\le 3.$

Comment: Is $R=\{(x, y) : 1 ≤ x, y ≤ 2; x ≥ y\}?$ Note the ;. Or $x\le y$ instead of $x\ge y?$

Comment: when $$(x,y)=(100,2)$$ $(x,y)$ is in the region since $y \le 2$ and $x \ge 1, \, x \ge y$ And you are assuming that $x \le 2$

Comment: No, it just has commas the whole way through, and $x \ge y$

Comment: There is a problem here. Have a look at region https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5Cge+1,+y%5Cle+2,+x%5Cge+y  It is unbounded.

Comment: @Isham Yes. So I think there is a typo in the definition of the region. I have assumed $1\le x,y \le 2$ as $1\le x\le 2, 1\le y \le 2.$ But this may not be the case.

Comment: Yes. In other case the integral is $\int_1^2 \int_{-\infty}^x dy dx+\int_2^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^2 dydx.$

Comment: I see that there must be a mistake... thanks for bearing with me